# assign new value to repeated (or multiple) objective element(s) to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AKey':[1, 9999, 1, 1, 9999, 2, 2, 2],\
    'AnotherKey':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
```

I want to assign a new value to a specific column and for each element having a specific value in that column.

Let say I want to assign the new value `8888` to the elements having value `9999`.
I tried the following:

```
df[df["AKey"]==9999]["AKey"]=8888
```

but it returns the following error:

`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

So I tried to use `loc`

```
df.loc[df["AKey"]==9999]["AKey"]=8888
```

which returned the same error.

I would appreciate some help and some explanation on the error as I really can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loc in this way:

```
df.loc[df["AKey"]==9999, "AKey"] = 8888
```

Producing the following output:

[image]

With your original code you are first slicing the dataframe with:

```
df.loc[df["AKey"]==9999]
```

Then assign a value for the sliced dataframe's column AKey.

```
["AKey"]=8888
```

In other words, you were updating the slice, not the dataframe itself.

From Pandas [documentatiom](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

> .loc[] is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean
>   array.

Breaking down the code:

```
df.loc[df["AKey"]==9999, "AKey"]
```

df["AKey"]==9999 will return a boolean array identifying the rows, and the string "Akey" will identify the column that will receive the new value, at once without slicing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you also elaborate on why this works and my previous tentative doesn't?

Comment: Edited the question with more details, @Gio

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution. It works if I use logical indexing to also identify the column.

```
df.loc[df["AKey"]==9999& df["AKey"]]=8888
```

However I would still appreciate help on the error I was receiving as it is not fully clear to me why Python thought that I was slicing instead of indexing